# VLQ flags of bad answers declined

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251070) and found it littered with bad answers. I thusly downvoted and flagged three of them as VLQ. Reviewing my flags today, I found out that one was marked helpful while the other two were declined, and I'm now flagging-banned (which is curious, as my last declined flag was more than 2 months ago).

The question asks for a way of removing the last file extension from a filename in bash. Here are the full two answers that are apparently not very low quality for such a question:

> using grep, and regular expression

For starters, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251165/1110381) has [an earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18251165/revisions) in which it was a clarification request (and thus NAA), as the first question revision didn't specify the language. Once OP specified the language, the "answer" was edited it into its current state, which is complete BS for anybody who knows a bit of bash. I'm not even aware of any way to manipulate text with grep, and even if it were possible, using grep to strip a file extension would amount to attempt sewing with a fork instead of a needle. The answerer also completely ignored OPs timely request for clarification. I figure the poster was out of their league and simply wrote random crap which they figured might potentially be useful.

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251204/1110381) reads:

> str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'))

Seems fine - except for the fact that it's JavaScript instead of bash! I wrote a comment stating it's the wrong language (although I initially misidentified it as python, which is rather embarrassing - the `str` probably threw me off).

---

I'm stil under the impression that both answers have severe content problems, cannot be improved by editing (only by removing all of the old text and replacing it with something else) and should be deleted. The following questions arise:

- Is there a reason why I should not have flagged the answers?
- Assuming I was correct in flagging the answers, should I have done anything different to ensure correct handling of the flags? Was the "that's the wrong language" comment not enough?
- Is it possible to get unbanned so that I can flag more crap?

Answer (score 6):

VLQ flags are first handled by the community, in the Low Quality review queue, but it here a moderator declined your flags.

The answers you flagged should just have been *voted down*. They are *terrible* answers, but they should not be deleted for that. Editing them is not going to turn them into better answers. No community involvement is going to change this.

Note the description on the VLQ flag:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

The posts do not have such problems. They use English, reasonable grammar, and are formatted correctly.

Had a post been written in a foreign language and you cannot make out if they are attempting to answer, flag it as VLQ. If the post is long and every other word has been bolded or made italic and editing all that out would take some time, flag it as VLQ.

But when the answer being plain, flat out wrong or unhelpful, you just vote. It doesn't matter here that the wrong programming language was used or that they are no more than an unhelpful vague remark.

The alternative would be that we'd require the Low Quality review queue reviewers to start judging the answers on their technical merit, to validate that the answer is indeed wrong in the context of the question. That's not the goal of that review, however.

Flag bans are based *only* on flags *handled* in the past 7 days (see [this post by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)). It doesn't matter when the flags were cast, it is when they are marked as helpful or not that determines if they currently count. You'll be able to flag soon enough again.

Comment: I thought community handled flags are marked as "disputed", not declined - does that differ for VLQ? And furthermore, why exactly should a post that says "use grep" not be deleted? Both posts do have severe **content** problems, in that you could replace the content with any random piece of code and it would make just as little sense. This definitely fits the VLQ description IMO.

Comment: So, does your answer apply both to the useless answer in the right language, as well as the one in the completely unrelated language? Or do you want to differentiate that some more?

Comment: @l4mpi: there is an attempt at answering there. It is a terrible attempt, but not the kinds of *content problems* VLQ flags were meant for.

Comment: @Deduplicator: it applies to both. Both are terrible, rotten answers and you just downvote.

Comment: @l4mpi: I think a community Low Quality review does indeed result in *disputed* flags, so a moderator declined these explicitly.

Comment: That's the same bad reasoning as is the case with NAA. Why not delete these "terrible, rotten answers"? Why differentiate between NAA and VLQ at all if both are only accepted if the post reads "I like tomatoes"?

Comment: @l4mpi: "Try throwing tomatoes at the monitor until the string is split" is trolling. It has content problems. It is a joke answer and deserves a VLQ flag. Although I'd probably use a custom flag to have the account deleted if there are no other positive contributions to redeem the account.

Comment: @l4mpi: *Gebruik the `grep` functie om het eerste deel uit de text te halen, inclusief een extensie dat bestaat uit alphabetische letters: `code sample`* has content problems, because it is in Dutch, not English, and Google Translate is not going to be able to produce a decent substitute.

Comment: Well, you give examples of other crap that should be deleted, but give no reasons why we should keep the crap I flagged around. I take the "No community involvement is going to change this" of your post to mean _this should be deleted with extreme prejudice_. I don't see any good reasons _why_ a terrible answer should be alowed to stick around. And I'd even challenge the assumption that the grep one is an answer at all, for me it feels like once the poster figured out the question is about bash they simply threw any random bash command in there to make it seem like an answer.

Comment: @l4mpi: so we are going to put the burden on the reviewers to now read the context, determine that the answer is technically unsound, and vote to delete? Why is *downvoting not enough*?

Comment: Because it's terrible and a waste of space; and because downvoting an answer that doesn't get deleted would permanently cost me rep and thus does not scale all to well (I come across a lot of crap, and usually similarily bad answers were deleted in the past when I flagged them). Note that you don't have to be an expert in bash or JS to figure out if an answer with a comment stating "that's a JS answer to a bash question" is LQ or not - I know that we don't expect reviewers to have knowledge of the reviewed tags but that's exactly why I left a comment clearly explaining the problem.

Comment: @l4mpi: the difference between the examples I gave and these posts is that *no technical judgement* is required to recognise the crap. I understand that the posts go against all technical decency, so we downvote it. But the posts are still perfectly readable.

Comment: @l4mpi: it costs you **one lousy rep point**. Please don't use that as an excuse to call in the review firing squad.

Comment: @l4mpi: I see the VLQ flag as the third option after *spam* and *offensive* here too. I reserve it for outright trolling mostly.

Comment: AFAIK, community-declined flags do not come with a message, but I could be wrong. A mod could decline a flag without a message by bypassing validation, but we generally have no reason to do that. That's just about the only way I can think of to differentiate between a community-declined and a mod-declined flag.

Comment: @BoltClock so "disputed" is only for specific flag types?

Comment: @l4mpi: I'm not sure what decides whether a community flag gets disputed or declined.

Comment: @BoltClock looking at it again, I think the flag was definitely declined by a mod as it explicitly states "a moderator reviewed your flag [...]" - I doubt that message is ever used for community-declined flags as the wording would otherwise be wrong. BTW Martijn, slight highjack but how does your answer this apply to [this non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19030470/1110381)? I went over my other declined answer flags, and this NAA was declined even though the "answer" just consists of counter questions - probably due to the upvotes, even though it IMO doesn't contain anything helpful?

Comment: @l4mpi: hrmz. That's not an answer. That's a comment. I downvoted it and flagged it with NAA. Lets see what happens.

Comment: @l4mpi: Correct. Also, "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies" does not mention moderators, but it is also one of our canned messages. The rest of our canned messages do. And if you see something that appears to be personalized, or is written in sentence case with punctuation, chances are it came from a mod as well.

Comment: @BoltClock: you mean moderators know how to spell?! Learn something new every day! :-P

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You jest, but, seriously, canned decline messages do not ever start with a sentence cap. But I'll tell you a secret: neither do mine :P That's why I also say "personalized".

Comment: Just to add to this, sometimes the VLQ flag doesn't give us enough information. In the case of the answer that was in JavaScript when the question was asking for a bash script, a custom flag probably would have gotten the answer deleted. A moderator looking at a VLQ flag will almost always miss that context.

Comment: @BilltheLizard "A moderator looking at a VLQ flag will almost always miss that context" - even though there was a comment stating that it's the wrong language? It's basically the same thing I'd have written into a custom mod flag but instead decided to comment and flag as VLQ instead as it didn't need mod attention, just deletion.

Comment: @l4mpi We don't see comments in the moderator queue. We only see the question title, the answer, and your flag. We often make decisions based on whether the post looks like it *could be* an answer because we don't always have subject matter expertise. That's the main reason we want VLQ flags to only be used for specific types of posts.

Comment: @BilltheLizard ok, that clarifies the issue enormously - the question title doesn't contain a language and the answer would make sense if the question would be tagged with JS. I was under the impression that you have a similar interface to the VLQ queue itself, where one sees the full question as well as any comments on the answer. So, looks like another case of suboptimal flag handling due to inadequate mod tools (just like my last issue with comment flags). All I've heard about the mod queue so far makes me think it is in desperate need of a few improvements, would you agree with that?

Comment: @l4mpi It seems like there have been constant improvements since I started using the mod queue, so it's hard to complain. We tend to just change our behavior until we get good at using a tool despite its limitations. That said, there's always room for improvement.